# How products in Top and Set are related?

Tags: general-topology, category-theory

Are product morphisms for a categorical product in **Top** the same as for categorical product morphisms in **Set**?

More generally: How product morphisms for **Top** are characterized?

Comment: What is a "product morphism"? This is not standard terminology.

Comment: @ZhenLin: McLane

Comment: I don't find any mentioning of a product morphism in Mac Lane. Are you talking about projections?

Comment: @ZhenLin http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_%28category_theory%29 - "product of morphisms"

Comment: That isn't standard terminology at all. See [this MO question](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/104494/product-operation-name-and-notation).

Comment: the most used name for this is: pairing morphism or tupling morphism (if more than 2 morphisms are used) you can see this in nlab under *product* and *pairing*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Products in $\textbf{Top}$ are "the same" as in $\textbf{Set}$ in the following sense:

- If $X_i$ ($i \in I$) is a family of topological spaces, then the underlying set of the product $\prod_i X_i$ is the product of the underlying sets, and the projections in $\textbf{Top}$ are the same as in $\textbf{Set}$.
- Similarly for the relationship between a family of continuous maps $f_i : Y \to X_i$ and the combined map $f = \langle f_i \rangle : Y \to \prod_i X_i$.

But that is all we are able to say. In technical terms, the above amounts to claiming that the forgetful functor $U : \textbf{Top} \to \textbf{Set}$ preserves all small products. One can prove this by abstract nonsense by observing that $U$ has a left adjoint, namely the functor $\textbf{Set} \to \textbf{Top}$ that equips a set with the discrete topology. It is *not* true that $U$ reflects or creates products: this is because there are in general many possible topologies on the *set* $\prod_i X_i$ that make the projections $\pi_j : \prod_i X_i \to X_j$ continuous without necessarily having the universal property of a product.

If we restrict to the full subcategory $\textbf{KHaus}$ of compact Hausdorff spaces, it *is* true that the forgetful functor $U : \textbf{KHaus} \to \textbf{Set}$ preserves *and* reflects all small products. This is because $\textbf{Haus}$ is monadic over $\textbf{Set}$ – roughly speaking, this means $\textbf{KHaus}$ behaves a bit like a category of algebraic structures.